# Ruby `gem` command fails SSL verification on self-hosted gemserver

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, haproxy

I've got a Ruby Gemserver running via [Geminabox](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox) over http on port 9392.

It's behind an HAProxy load balancer which is enforcing https and doing SSL termination. Here's the relevant chunk(s) of my haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 256
    user nobody
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms
    option httpclose

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend www-https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/***********.pem
    default_backend home_server

    acl is_gems             hdr(host) -i gems.example.com
    use_backend gems        if is_gems

backend gems
    server gems1 192.168.100.102:9392 ssl verify none
```

When I try to add my gemserver from any other machine:

```
Error fetching https://gems.example.com:
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://gems.boynton.io/specs.4.8.gz)
```

**What's interesting is this remains true whether the gemserver is running or not, leading me to believe my local ruby `gem` client is rejecting the cert out of the gate.** (Otherwise I'd have stuck this question in ServerFault)

The cert is a Comodo PositiveSSL Wildcard cert, not a self-signed. I've confirmed the CA cert is in my local trust store (I'm on OS X El Cap, so it's been added to my keychain). It seems like maybe the `gem` command isn't using my system trust store.

I've googled around on this for two or three days to no avail -- everything I can find relates to rubygems.org and suggests `gem update --system` (I'm running the latest rubygems) or switching to `http`, both of which are rubygems.org-specific fixes.

How can I get `gem` to use my local trust store or take an additional cert?